# Call not found in laravel Vinkla\Instagram package

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting this error while using the Vinkla\Instagram package for instafeed Class 'Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider' not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"require: {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^1.2"**
}
```

Seems that you are using the php 5.* and that's why composer pulling the 1.2 version of the package which has different class.

I got the same problem a month ago

The read me file that you read to setup package is for 2.4 version which is for php 7.0

Just update your php 5.* to php 7.* or get the read me file of 1.2 version of package to setup package correctly

I've written an article about this on my blog: [Class not found error due to php version mismatch](http://www.mchampaneri.in/2017/03/debug-errors-of-external-packages-used.html)

Comment: I'm guessing that's a link to your blog - please edit your answer to say that, otherwise it will be considered spam, leading a possible worst result of your account being blocked

Comment: I also suggest reading this [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)